# Scrape data with Ghost

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, ghost.py

I want to scrap some data on the following link:

http://www.six-structured-products.com/en/search-find/new-search#search_type=profi&class_category=svsp

My target is simply to retrieve the table of all instruments (displayed in "search results" on page 1,2,3, etc) in a `data.frame`.
I can't simply use `urllib` and `urllib2` to retrieve static data since I need to mimic a human by cliking on buttons: `Ghost` or `Selenium` are the way to go.

However, I really do not get how to translate into code "click on page 2", "click on page 3" ... as well as getting the total number of pages.

My code:

```
from ghost import Ghost

url = "http://www.six-structured-products.com/en/search-find/new-search#search_type=profi&class_category=svsp"

gh = Ghost()
page, resources = gh.open(url)
```

I am stuck there and do not know which identifier to put instead of XXX:

```
page, resources = ghost.evaluate(
"document.getElementById(XXX).click();", expect_loading=True)
```

(I would also accept a solution using `Selenium`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the next button this way:

```
import logging
import sys

from ghost import Ghost, TimeoutError


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

url = "http://www.six-structured-products.com/en/search-find/new-search#search_type=profi&class_category=svsp"

ghost = Ghost(wait_timeout=20, log_level=logging.CRITICAL)
data = dict()


def extract_value(line, ntd):
    return line.findFirst('td.DataItem:nth-child(%d)' % ntd).toPlainText()


def extract(ghost):
    lines = ghost.main_frame.findAllElements(
        '.derivativeSearchResult > tbody:nth-child(2) tr'
    )

    for line in lines:
        symbol = extract_value(line, 2)
        name = extract_value(line, 5)
        logging.info("Found %s: %s" % (symbol, name))
        # Persist data here

    ghost.sleep(1)

    try:
        ghost.click('.pagination_next a', expect_loading=True)
    except TimeoutError:
        sys.exit(0)

    extract(ghost)


ghost.open(url)
extract(ghost)
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer!! Really really clear, expect the PySide object and QtWebkit I am not familiar at all ... for example, how can I access using object `lines[0]` , the value of attribute `data-isin` in the first `td` ? And the title of the image located in the 6th `td` (the value is Deutsche bank)?

Comment: It's alright, jquery syntax was far away from my knowledge but it's well documented :)

Answer (score 1):

Make an endless loop incrementing the page index. Exit the loop when you don't find the button with a current index:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.six-structured-products.com/en/search-find/new-search#search_type=profi&class_category=svsp')

page = 2  # starting page
while True:
    try:
        button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@id="pagination_pages"]/li[@class="pagination_page" and . = "%d"]' % page)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        break

    time.sleep(1)
    button.click()

    page += 1

print page  # total number of pages

driver.close()
```

Note that instead of a `time.sleep()`, a more reliable approach would be to use [Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! But a quesiton: how did you got the button path:
'//ul[@id="pagination_pages"]/li[@class="pagination_page" and . = "5"]' for page 5 for example? I do not find it so obvious even if I can locate in the html source code where are the buttons...

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel used browser developer tools to inspect the element. Then, just came up with an idea to check the page number (element's text).

Comment: Hum I have this error but it may be because I am using Chrome ...*** WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at
element would receive the click: <span class="BookmarksTitle">...</span>
  (Session info: chrome=39.0.2171.95)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)